# Generated files in angular2 AoT compilation

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-compiler-cli

I'm using angular-cli to build an app.
The build runs fine with the `--aot=false` option.

I get errors with `--aot=true`, and to investigate these I'd like to look at the files generated by the compilation (ngFactory files in particular).
However I can't seem to get the files to be persisted to disk so I can look at them...

Here's my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "aot"
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "exclude": ["test.ts"],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "aot",
    "debug": true,
    "skipMetadataEmit": true
    }
}
```

When compiling with `--target=production` (implies `--aot=true`), I get the error:

```
ERROR in /home/application/aot/app/composition.component.ngfactory.ts (79,9): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
```

**What I want is to open the `composition.component.ngfactory.ts` file to debug it**.

However when the ng build completes the file does not exist (as if it had been 'cleaned'). There's no `aot` directory either.
If I create the `aot` directory it remains empty.

Any help appreciated!

Edit: Even creating a new project with `ng new` (angular-cli 1.0.0) I can't seem to get the intermediate files in aot compilation to be written to disk.

Comment: Do you have a repo to reproduce it?

Comment: i had a similar problem. after deleting the /compiled directory (thats where my compiled files went) and re-compiling the project it was fine. so try finding the directory - delete the whole directory or just that one file - and recompile it

Comment: Might want to follow up here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5619

Comment: Thanks @BrandonSilva that's exactly what I'm looking for. I missed that issue in my googling around apparently. I felt the docs suggested it was already possible to get these files though.